# How to use the ? mark to bind values in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Generally you will have a query like this:

```
$qry = $this->db->prepare(" SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE status = :status ");
$qry->execute(array(':status'=>'whatever value'));
```

So what I want to do is something like this:

```
$qry = $this->db->prepare(" SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE status = ? ");
$qry->execute(array('whatever value'));
```

Is there some sort of attribute one can set to accomplish this?

Comment: This may sound totally insane, buy you can [read the manual on the subject](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and maybe it'll give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks, noob moment!

Comment: That's okay. At least you're trying to do the right thing.

Comment: You can do that, but its less readable, look at this tutorial here. - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Comment: Just as an aside, I way prefer using named parameters if poss. So much more readable and debuggerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array(150, 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thanks, stupid of me not to have tried that first :)